Error loading dependency. "dash" is not a registered library
I'm receiving the dash error message "Error loading dependency. "dash" is not a registered library.", but not consistently. My dashboard is hosted on an internal server, and runs absolutely fine most of the time, but then gets in a failure loop with the following stack trace:
ERROR Exception on /_dash-component-suites/dash/dcc/dash_core_components.v2_14_1m1722340505.js 
[GET] | asctime=2024-08-06 07:16:27,592 name=datadashboard.app levelname=ERROR 
exc_info=Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1473, in wsgi_app
     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 882, in full_dispatch_request
     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 880, in full_dispatch_request
     rv = self.dispatch_request()
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 865, in dispatch_request
     return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)  # type: ignore[no-any-return]
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/dash/dash.py", line 989, in serve_component_suites
     _validate.validate_js_path(self.registered_paths, package_name, path_in_pkg)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/dash/_validate.py", line 373, in validate_js_path
     raise exceptions.DependencyException( dash.exceptions.DependencyException: Error loading dependency. "dash" is not a registered library. Registered libraries are: []
timestamp=2024-08-06T07:16:27.616464Z

From this, it seems as though no libraries are being registered, so I'm wondering where it's going wrong? I can't seem to replicate it locally, and have tried googling which just links to dependency errors rather than missing registered libraries
For info, i am using dash version 2.17.1, dbc version 1.6.1rc2 and dash-daq version 0.5.0

It could be because you are using wrong venv (Virtual Environment) file or IDE error.
You could try the following:

Try restart your IDE.
Check the virtual environment you are using.
Check for Updates

pip install dash --upgrade
pip install dash-bootstrap-components --upgrade
pip install dash-daq --upgrade

It could be network issue check the network you are connecting.
Finally try to replicate your local python version and libraries like the server side.


the virtual environment it uses on the server gets rebuilt through a ci/cd process each time it's deployed, using the latest versions of dash/dbc/dash-daq, so i think that's not the issue. I'll try using the local versions on the server though (y)
